# Variations of "I'll let you know when it's done"

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Do all these sentences mean the same thing or are there any subtle differences among them?

> I'll let you know when it's done.
>
> I'll let you know when done.
>
> I'll let you know when it has been done.
>
> I'll let you know when I've done it.
>
> I'll let you know once it's done.
>
> I'll let you know once done.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between them?

Comment: There is always *some* difference between any sentences that use different words or a different word order.

Comment: Obviously No. 4 only applies if you are doing the task yourself, while the rest could refer to others doing it, with or without your help.